# little problem on code for finding substring within string scala

Tags: string, scala, substring

I am currently working on a small code that should allow to tell if a given substring is within a string. I checked all the other similar questions but everybody is using predefined functions. I need to build it from scratch… could you please tell me what I did wrong?

```
def substring(s: String, t: String): Boolean ={
 var i = 0 // position on substring
 var j = 0 // position on string
 var result = false
 var isSim = true
 var n = s.length // small string size
 var m = t.length // BIG string size


// m must always be bigger than n + j
while (m>n+j && isSim == true){
// j grows with i
// stopping the loop at i<n
while (i<n && isSim == true){
  // if characters are similar
  if (s(i)==t(j)){
    // add 1 to i. So j will increase by one as well
    // this will run the loop looking for similarities. If not, exit the loop.
    i += 1
    j = i+1
    // exciting the loop if no similarity is found
  }
  // answer given if no similarity is found
  isSim = false
}
}
   // printing the output
    isSim
}

substring("moth", "ramathaaaaaaa")
```

Comment: `substring("moth", "ramathaaaaaaa")` returns `false`. What's the problem?

Comment: Yes, but `substring("math", "ramathaaaaaaa")` returns false too...

Comment: my recomendation for this type of problems, is to use a debugger. For instance, Intellij offers a very easy to use (and powerful) debugger. You should then go step by step, following your algorithm, until you see where is it doing domething wrong

Comment: Okay I will, thank you!

Comment: are you using any known algorithm? because substring finding is not as trivial as it seems, since you need to return to a previous position in some cases: for instance find 'mamh' in 'xxxmamamhxx'

Comment: No, I am not Using any algorithm. By the way I cleaned all my errors, thanks for the advice on Intellij.

Comment: Yet the answer is Always "false"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem consists of two subproblems of same kind. You have to check whether

- there **exists** a start index `j` such that
- **for all** `i <- 0 until n` it holds that `substring(i) == string(j + i)`

Whenever you have to check whether some predicate holds for some / for all elements of a sequence, it can be quite handy if you can short-circuit and exit early by using the `return` keyword. Therefore, I'd suggest to eliminate all variables and `while`-loops, and use a nested method instead:

```
def substring(s: String, t: String): Boolean ={
  val n = s.length // small string size
  val m = t.length // BIG string size

  def substringStartingAt(startIndex: Int): Boolean = {
    for (i <- 0 until n) {
      if (s(i) != t(startIndex + i)) return false
    }
    true
  }

  for (possibleStartIndex <- 0 to m - n) {
    if (substringStartingAt(possibleStartIndex)) return true
  }

  false
}
```

The inner method checks whether **all** `s(j + i) == t(i)` for a given `j`. The outer `for`-loop checks whether there **exists** a suitable offset `j`.

Example:

```
for (
  (sub, str) <- List(
    ("moth", "ramathaaaaaaa"),
    ("moth", "ramothaaaaaaa"),
    ("moth", "mothraaaaaaaa"),
    ("moth", "raaaaaaaamoth"),
    ("moth", "mmoth"),
    ("moth", "moth"),
  )
) {
  println(sub + " " + " " + str + ": " + substring(sub, str))
}
```

output:

```
moth  ramathaaaaaaa: false
moth  ramothaaaaaaa: true
moth  mothraaaaaaaa: true
moth  raaaaaaaamoth: true
moth  mmoth: true
moth  moth: true
```

If you were allowed to use built-in methods, you could of course also write

```
def substring(s: String, t: String): Boolean = {
  val n = s.size
  val m = t.size
  (0 to m-n).exists(j => (0 until n).forall(i => s(i) == t(j + i)))
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this really helped! I will try avoiding while loops in the future.

Comment: @Data_Gengar No, please, don't "try to avoid *<insert-currently-less-fashionable-language-feature-here>*". Try to understand when a language feature is useful, and when it is less useful, and why, and then try to apply it when appropriate, and don't apply it where it's not appropriate. In this particular case, if you really cared about performance, it probably wouldn't hurt to replace the function call by a `while`-loop, but it would be quite a hassle with indices and boolean flags.

Answer (score 0):

I offer the following slightly more idiomatic Scala code, not because I think it will perform better than Andrey's code--I don't--but simply because it uses recursion and is, perhaps, slightly easier to read:

```
  /**
    * Method to determine if "sub" is a substring of "string".
    *
    * @param sub    the candidate substring.
    * @param string the full string.
    * @return true if "sub" is a substring of "string".
    */
  def substring(sub: String, string: String): Boolean = {
    val p = sub.toList

    /**
      * Tail-recursive method to determine if "p" is a subsequence of "s"
      *
      * @param s the super-sequence to be tested (part of the original "string").
      * @return as follows:
      *         (1) "p" longer than "s" => false;
      *         (2) "p" elements match the corresponding "s" elements (starting at the start of "s") => true
      *         (3) recursively invoke substring on "p" and the tail of "s".
      */
    @tailrec def substring(s: Seq[Char]): Boolean = p.length <= s.length && (
      s.startsWith(p) || (
        s match {
          case Nil => false
          case _ :: z => substring(z)
        }
        )
      )

    p.isEmpty || substring(string.toList)
  }
```

If you object to using the built-in method *startsWith* then we could use something like:

```
(p zip s forall (t => t._1==t._2))
```

But we have to draw the line somewhere between creating everything from scratch and using built-in functions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I'm just starting the chapter on recursive algortihms and I will soon understand this code better!